# Angular2: What is diagnostic property in forms

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-services, angular2-forms

I don't understand this paragraph from angular2 site:

> We threw in a diagnostic property at the end to return a JSON representation of our model. It'll help us see what we're doing during our development; we've left ourselves a cleanup note to discard it later.

[Here is the link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)

What does it mean

Comment: Hard to tell without context. The Angular2 site has a lot of content. Would you mind sharing a link that points to the location where you got this text from?

Comment: Could you include a link to that citation? It is probably easier to answer the question if you provide the context the statement occurs in.

Comment: updated my qiestion

Answer (score 6):

They just added a getter `diagnostic` to get the model as string. Then they add `{{diagnostic}}` to the template to make the raw model visible while testing the form to always see if the model is updated when they edit the form.

```
`{{model | json}}`
```

would do the same.